# number subequations within a displayed equation

Tags: equations, numbering

I would like to add a standard equation number to each of the rows in the aligned environment below

```
\begin{equation}
   a=b
   \Leftrightarrow
   \left\{
   \begin{aligned}
      a \leq b\\ b \leq a
   \end{aligned}
   \right.
\end{equation}
```

What is a good way to achieve this result (I tried changing `aligned` by `split` or even an `array`, and addding `\tag`s but I am not able to make it work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `empheq`, which lets you define what's on the left part of equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={ a=b \Leftrightarrow \empheqlbrace}]{align}
      a \leq b\\
      b \leq a
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks Bernard! I undesrtand that there is no (direct) way to do it without loading extra-ams packages, is that right?

Comment: Not really, because `empheq`  is an extension of `amsmath`, which loads the former and `mathtools`

Answer (score 1):

You need not any package, moreover: you need not LaTeX-:)

```
$$
  a = b ⇔ \cases {a ≤ b \cr b ≤ a} 
  \eqno \displaystyle \matrix {(1)\cr(2)}
$$
\bye
```

Comment: This is an *ad hoc* solution that won't work if the cases have unusual height and depth. And you are not telling how to get *automatic* numbering.

Comment: Automatic numbering depends on used macro collection (OpTeX, LaTeX, etc.). I show only format independent solution here.